# Trouble with exponentiation in Octave's ezmesh function

Tags: matlab, operators, octave

I made the following function handler:

```
fhapprox1 = @(x, y) sum ([1:x] .^ y)
```

This works fine when called with arguments like `fhapprox1(3,5)`. However, when passing this function to `ezmesh` (using `ezmesh(fhapprox1)`), I get the following error:

```
error: operator .^: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x0, op2 is 60x60)
```

What is happening here? How can I rewrite this to get the 3d graph I'm expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your function is only designed to handle single values of `x` and `y`.  `ezmesh` uses a grid of co-ordinates and `x` and `y` are actually 2D matrices when you use `ezmesh`.  You get undefined behaviour when trying to call up `ezmesh` this way.  In addition, `ezmesh` plots between `-2*pi <= (x,y) <= 2*pi` by default.

Because `x` can be `< 0`, doing `1:x` when `x` is negative will give you an empty array, which is why you get that error.  You need to rethink how your function can be defined so that it takes in a grid of co-ordinates and outputs the values you want.  I can't provide anything further because I don't know how your function would be defined for negative values of `x`.  Once I get this information, I'll update my answer.

---

## Edit

We can modify your `fhapprox1` function so that it can take in a grid of values.  I can't think of a way to vectorize this code right now other than doing nested `for` loops, but let's try and get something working first.  Basically, make a separate M-file that's called `fhapprox1.m`.  After, put this into the file:

```
function [Z] = fhapprox1(X, Y)

Z = zeros(size(X));

for x = 1 : size(X,1)
    for y = 1 : size(X,2)
        Z(x,y) = sum((1:X(x,y)) .^ Y(x,y));
    end
end
```

The above code will do what you were doing for single values of `(x,y)`, but now it can take in a **grid** of `(x,y)` co-ordinates.  By doing this, then calling `ezmesh` in the way you specified in your comments, this is what we get:

```
ezmesh(@fhapprox1, [1,1000,1,3])
```

[image]

Comment: Im hoping my function wouldn't be defined for negative values. Specifying the dimensions using `ezmesh(fhapprox1, [1,1000,1,3])` gives error `X,Y,Z must have same dimensions` but I suspect thats a different problem. Thanks for solving this one!

Comment: @ForrestKeppler - Cool!  So you restricted the plot to positive values.  That error is because your function still needs to take in a grid of values, and output another grid of values.  If you wish, I can update my answer as I know what you're after.   Let me know if you want an update!

Comment: I would love an updated answer! I havent done much linear algebra so its a little difficult to wrap my head around what Im supposed to be doing here.

Comment: @ForrestKeppler - Not a problem.  I updated my answer.  Good luck!